# Execute Callback(obj) if callback Exists Else return object

Tags: javascript, callback

What I'm trying to do is make the callback parameter to a function optional.  If a callback is passed send the value to the callback function else simply return the value.  If I omit the callback I get undefined returned.

```
getByUsername = function(user_name, cb){
    async.waterfall([
        //Acquire SQL connection from pool
        function(callback){
            sql_pool.acquire(function(err, connection){
                callback(err, connection);
            });
        },
        //Verify credentials against database
        function(connection, callback){
            var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?';
            var inserts = ['users','user_name', user_name];
            sql = mysql.format(sql,inserts);
            connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
                sql_pool.release(connection);
                callback(err, results);   
            });
        },
        //Create user object
        function(results, callback) {
            if(results.length < 1){
                if(cb){
                    cb(null);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }else {
                var thisUser = new User(results[0]);
                if(cb){
                    cb(thisUser);
                } else {
                    return thisUser;
                }
            }
        }], function (err, results) {
            throw new Error('errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrroooooorrrrrrrr');
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: haha.  sorry.  It doesn't work properly. I get callback not defined.

Comment: It should be somewhat obvious. Look at the name of the arguments. Also, why would you call the callback if it's null?

Comment: drrr.  Thanks Evan!  It was pretty obvious.  This does work when I correct my errors.  I was trying to save you from my actual code (which is much longer & likely horrible).  I'll update the example above with my actual code after I sniff it for a similar mistake.   :-)

Comment: Updated the code to what I'm actually using.  I apologize, I'm sure it's apparent I'm very new at this.  :-)   If I use the callback all is well.  If I don't pass the callback I get undefined.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could just check like this:

```
if(cb && typeof cb === "function") {
    cb(num + 1);
}
```

NOTE: Make sure you're actually using `cb` to call your callback function and not `callback` ;)

Comment: `&& typeof cb === "function")` if you want to double check type safety

Comment: Thanks zero298. I added that to the condition. BTW, no need for `===` since `typeof` operator always "returns" string, or null, so simple comparison fo `"function"` would work just fine.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll definitely work these suggestions into my code.  I updated my example to be my actual code as my previous example was well, a failure (lesson learned).  I was able to get the previous example to work after fixing my errors, but this I cannot nor readily see my mistakes.  Thanks again!

Comment: `===` is faster than `==` because `==` compares it to each type.

Comment: `===` is faster and more consistent/less tricky, D. Crockford recommends this approach and ESLint rules check it, for example. But IMHO first part is redundant because of the second makes all the work. If `cb` is not defined/declared (not undefined) `TypeError` will be thrown. So the comprehensive solution should use `try/catch`.